# How to indent second line in lists when the bullet has a background?

Tags: css, html-lists, font-awesome

I have a unordered list where the bullets are created with FontAwesome, a bit of background and a border radius.

I want the second line of text be be alined below the first one and not under the bullet.

```
li::before {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: .3em;
    content: "\f00c";
    float: left;
    margin: 0 9px 0 0;
    font: 10px 'FontAwesome';
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #3498db;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Somehow `float: left` seems to "conflict" with `display: table-cell`.

Any ideas on how to get this to work? -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9b5u2v9/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `position:absolute` for `:before` and `padding-left` for `<li>`

```
li {
    position:relative;
    padding-left:32px;
}

li::before{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1oauqvav/)

Comment: In case you are using `left` the bullet will stick to parent container, not to the list item.

Comment: No, pseudo-elements are children of li

Comment: Just try to increase `padding-left` for `li` itself in your fiddle — bullet stays at the left side.

Comment: Ye, because padding is part of li.

Comment: So using this, we can not adjust any padding for `li` in future, ie. for sublists. Why?

Comment: You cam use left-margin for this

Comment: What if we can't use `margin-left` cause of styling (backgrounds, borders, etc.)?

Comment: "If we can't..." It is holy war. And your post is only copy of my with your option.

Comment: Guys... thank you for your quick answers. Please do not kill yourselves with CSS bullets :)

Comment: @Anon, It is not a copy, look for fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:absolute` for `:before` and `padding-left` for `<li>`, but do not use `left` or `top`. Use margins instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/semencov/vvLtj43g/

Comment: "but do not use left or top. Use margins instead. " What is it? Please, read CSS manual :)

Comment: You do not understand the principle of positioning elements. This is very sad.

Comment: This is your opinion.